# Simplified method for this?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For each $n\in\mathbb N_+$, let function $$f(n)=\begin{cases}0,&n\mbox{ is a perfect square,}\\\displaystyle{\left[\frac1{\{\sqrt n\}}\right]},&n\mbox{ isn’t a perfect square.}\end{cases}$$Find $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{240}f(k)$.

My method has large amount of calculation, so I’m looking for a better one. Basically I added the whole thing one by one after simple analysis for non-square $n$s.

$n=m^2+k,1\le k\le2m$ is a non-square, then $$f(n)=\left[\frac1{\sqrt n-m}\right]=\left[\frac{\sqrt{m^2+k}+m}k\right]=\left[\frac{2m}k\right].$$ By the way the bottom part of the formula after the second $=$ got cut off, could anyone fix it for me?

Then $$\sum_{k=1}^{240}f(k)=\sum_{m=1}^{14}\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\left[\frac{2m}k\right]+\sum_{k=1}^{15}\left[\frac{30}k\right]=768.$$ Luckily I got the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\left[\frac{2m}k\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{2m}d(k)$, where $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k$.